# How to achieve word-wrap: break-word behaviour in IE 6.0?

Tags: css, word-wrap

word-wrap doesn't seem to be supported in IE 6.0, judgying by IETester, although I read in a msdn article that is is supported.

How to achieve word-wrap: break-word behaviour in IE 6.0? e.g. using JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using * { zoom:1; } selector?

Comment: Are you set proper <!DOCTYPE > property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked in my IE6 with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
p{
  width:100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works fine.  See the pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap: break-word` started as an IE proprietary property/attribute and has been available since IE 5.5 ([source](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/02/firefox-ie-word-wrap-word-break-tables.html)). It was added to the CSS3 spec.